# Error in travis ci build

Tags: github, travis-ci

I'm having trouble in a build on Travis CI. I'm getting those errors on git and that's blocking me. I've tried to restart the build and stuff like that, but it didn't work. My .travis.yml:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "0.12"
 - "0.10"
branches:
 only:
  - v1.0.0_dev
  - v1.0.0_stable
before_script:
 - npm install -g bower
 - npm install -g gulp
 - npm install -g karma
 - bower install
 - gulp prod
```

And that's the error code:

```
0.53s$ git clone --depth=50 git://github.com/GUMGA/components.git
GUMGA/components
Cloning into 'GUMGA/components'...
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd GUMGA/components
3.08s$ git fetch origin +refs/pull/3/merge:
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/3/merge
The command "eval git fetch origin +refs/pull/3/merge:" failed. 
Retrying, 2 of 3.
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/3/merge
The command "eval git fetch origin +refs/pull/3/merge:" failed. 
Retrying, 3 of 3.
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/3/merge
The command "eval git fetch origin +refs/pull/3/merge:" failed 3 times.
The command "git fetch origin +refs/pull/3/merge:" failed and exited with   128 during. Your build has been stopped.
```

Comment: Can I get the link to your GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2):

You merged a pull request (here: #3) before:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/3/merge
```

---

Try to open the PR again or create a new commit!

Comment: Yes! In my case I already deleted the branch. I could restore it by going to the github's PR and click on `restore branch`. Then I went restart the travis build and voila.